# Графики в Unity

Tags: delphi, unity3d, диаграммы

Собираю переносить программу на unity. В программе строятся графики. В delphi есть UI TChart из коробки. В нём есть куча своих настроек. Что бы пользоваться необходимо просто заполнять массив SeriesList. Есть ли что-либо подобное на unity? Если нет встроенных, то есть ли уже созданные?

Пример UI TChart

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В Unity есть компонент [Line Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) - как видно из названия, он рисует линии. Тоже разные настройки есть и материал и толщина. Рисует по массиву вершин, который можно менять и в рантайме. Вероятно, вам подойдёт.

Comment: Прикрепил пример к вопросу, как я понимаю тут только линия, в TChart сразу идут оси с подписями

Comment: @RodGers, нет, в unity такого инструмента нет - это игровой движок. Вам придётся все собирать самому из других компонентов. Image для картинок, Text - для надписей и отдельно рисовать линии.

Answer (score 0):

Готового функционала нет, когда нам понадобилось писали самостоятельно, но это еще на 4 было. Недавно просматривал AssetStopre попадались плагины для рисования графиков, но чужими пользоваться не приходилось, поэтому поищите сами)